# How can I limit rows and prevent race conditions for a reservation system

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm building a reservation system for products. Let's say I have a product table with name and quantity fields ("my-tshirt", 2). I also have a reservations table, which maps product IDs to user IDs. How can make sure that there are only two reservation entries for that table? How can I prevent any race conditions? Do I need to worry about this? I've read for airlines and hotels people have said allot a 15 minute session, but I would prefer to make this real time, where once you tap the reserve button, we can instantly (instant being 0.1-5.0 seconds) tell you if you have a reservation or not.

I'm using Tornado, SQLAlchemy, Postgres, and am also using Redis for various things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes you do need to worry about race conditions. The way I would suggest handling the problem is using a FOR UPDATE select statement. This will allow you to find a row you're looking for, lock it, and update it without another thread coming in and querying or modifying it during the the time you're modifying it. Something like this should do the trick:

```
try:
    productToUpdate = session.query(Product).filter(Product.name == "my-tshirt", Product.quantity > 0).with_for_update().one() #assume Product.name is unique and name exists
except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound as e:
    return "No reservations available" #Handle no reservation case here
productToUpdate.quantity -= 1
newReservation = Reservation()
newReservation.product = productToUpdate #assume relationship setup
newReservation.user = userForReservation #assume relationship setup
session.commit()
```

Edit:

If you didn't want to update the product quantity and keep a separate count of reservations, there are two ways to handle things.

The first, as you asked in your question, is to take the sum of reservations from the reservations table and compare it to the product quantity available. I would advise against this because in order to avoid race conditions you would need to lock the reservations table from inserting rows, which would affect other threads and could slow things down drastically based on your table usage. Without locking the table another thread could insert a reservation after you queried the totals, before you created another entry.

The second method, and what I suggest, is to add a column to your Product table for reservation counts, and update that at the same time as your reservations table. This still leaves the possibility that a reservation could be inserted into the table after reading, but if your application doesn't insert into the reservations table without gaining a lock on the Product table you can ensure your data is accurate.

```
try:
    productToUpdate = session.query(Product).filter(Product.name == "my-tshirt", Product.quantity - Product.reservations >= quantityToReserve).with_for_update().one() #assume Product.name is unique and name exists
except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound as e:
    return "No reservations available" #Handle no reservation case here
productToUpdate.reservations += quantityToReserve
#can put in another query and logic here to see if you're updating a reservation, or creating a new one
newReservation = Reservation(reservationQuantity = quantityToReserve)
newReservation.product = productToUpdate #assume relationship setup
newReservation.user = userForReservation #assume relationship setup
session.commit()
```

Some reading on FOR UPDATE for postgres is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

Some reading on with_for_update() is [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_for_update)

Comment: Thanks. It is also probably worthwhile adding a constraint making sure inventory is > 0, right? Also, would I be able to achieve similar results using constraints. Let's say I didn't want to modify the quantity in the product table, but instead wanted the sum of the rows with the product id in the reservation table to be <= the quantity in the product table. Is that possible?

Comment: The code I posted assumes a quantity of one is used for each reservation, and checks to make sure at least one is left in the query filter. If you want to have more than one reserved at a time, then yes, add some more checking. As for not modifying the product quantity, I will expand my answer.

Comment: Those assumptions are correct in this scenario. Each reservation is for a single item. I see that the filter should sort of take care of the checking, and I probably wouldn't need a constraint.

Comment: I expanded my answer to not modify the product quantity in the table, and allow for a quantity of items per reservation. Let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: If I use with_for_update in a different process (say a worker), the lock will still apply, right? Is the lock a global/database level lock?